# $\mathbb{Q}[X]/\left(X^{2}-1\right)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

i need to prove that:
$\mathbb{Q}[X]/\left(X^{2}-1\right)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$, but i don't know where to start. I first wanted to use the Chinese value theorem, but i can't see how that should fit in. Hints/tricks/other theorems would be much apreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hint for using CRT: $X^2 - 1 = (X-1)(X+1)$.

Comment: @tobias this is very useful indeed, now i can use the chinese theorem because $X-1 + X+1 = R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Recall that $X^2 - 1 = (X+1)(X-1)$, so let us consider the map $T \colon \mathbb Q [X] \ni q \mapsto \bigl(q(1), q(-1)\bigr)\in \mathbb Q^2$. What can you say about $T$? Is it onto? What is its kernel?